# .htaccess - Rewrite with 3 variables but after that get the rest of the URL

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

So I'm currently using my .htaccess to write my URL to be more URL friendly.
But I'm having trouble getting the fourth variable that could be more folders. I'll try and explain it as best I can below.

So at the moment I have the following URL working:

*www.mysite.co.uk/first/second/third*

Now for this I am using the rewrite rule:

```
RewriteRule ^e/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]*)/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]*)/([a-zA-Z0-9\-\/]*)$ index.php?var_1=$1&var_2=$2&var_3=$3   [L]
```

My problem comes when I one of the following happens:

*www.mysite.co.uk/first/second/third/fourth*

*www.mysite.co.uk/first/second/third/fourth/fifth*

*www.mysite.co.uk/first/second/third/fourth/fifth/sixth*

From the above I want the following variables to be returned:

$_GET['var_1'] = **first**

$_GET['var_2'] = **second**

$_GET['var_3'] = **third/fourth**

*OR*

$_GET['var_3'] = **third/fourth/fifth**

*OR*

$_GET['var_3'] = **third/fourth/fifth/sixth**

So basically I always have a 'var_1' and 'var_2' set but the third variable can be the rest of the URL.

I hope this makes sense and that it's possible.

Comment: You could do this trough php, parse url:
examples here: [ http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php ]

Comment: Hi @DenisSolakovic thanks for the input. Doing could work but it works better when variables are sent in the original format (?var_one= first).

Unless I'm missing something.

Comment: Hmm, you could probably do it with .htaccess [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7827779/htaccess-url-rewrite-with-variables] , but my other suggestion is to explode url parameter with delimiter / and fetch your url fragments...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you your rule starts with **^e/**
if your urls will be in format : www.mysite.co.uk/**e**/first/second/third/fourth
then use this regex:

```
RewriteRule ^e/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)(/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+))?(/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]*))?$ index.php?var_1=$1&var_2=$3&var_3=$5 [L]
```

If you need it without /e/ at start ***www.mysite.co.uk/e/first/second/third/fourth***
then remove /e/ from start

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)(/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+))?(/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]*))?$ index.php?var_1=$1&var_2=$3&var_3=$5 [L]
```

Example above will work even with url-s like **/first** and **/first/second** but if you don't need it and you want to have this rule just in case of 3 or more params then you can simplify rule:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)$ index.php?var_1=$1&var_2=$2&var_3=$3 [L]
```